# Bug in the Finder on Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: macos, finder, ventura

Since I changed my Mac for a new one and reinstalled my file system from a backup, I have many problems with the Finder to find my folders.

A typical example is the following:

- in the Finder, if I control+click on the (current) folder name in the menu bar, I see the parent folder tree.
- If I click on one of them, I don't get to that folder, but to / (root).

How can I solve this problem?

Additional information (based on the answers received):

- This only happens for certain folders and I have not been able to identify why some folders have this problem and others do not.
- In addition, any search through Spotlight in these directories will fail.
- I am showing below what happens:

  - if I click on `2023_05_07` or `Reunions-Talks`, it will bring me to the correct folder
  - if I click on `03-xxx`and below, it will bring me to `/`

[image]

Hi @nohillside, result of command `ls -leO@pd ~/Documents/0_Travail ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-* ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-*/Reunions-Talks` is:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 myself  staff  -  352 22 avr 13:43 /Users/myself/Documents/0_Travail/
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@ 23 myself  staff  -  736 22 avr 12:05 /Users/myself/Documents/0_Travail/03-*/
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@ 38 myself  staff  - 1216 27 avr 18:57 /Users/myself/Documents/0_Travail/03-*/Reunions-Talks/
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32
```

Result of command `xattr -r -d com.apple.FinderInfo ~/Documents` is:

```
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/myself/Documents/2_Biblio/29_AutoPapers/Berns03a.pdf'
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/myself/Documents/2_Biblio/29_AutoPapers/Miliani07a.pdf'
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/myself/Documents/2_Biblio/29_AutoPapers/Lazzari10.pdf'
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/myself/Documents/2_Biblio/29_AutoPapers/Perrut13.pdf'
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/myself/Documents/2_Biblio/29_AutoPapers/Djomgoue13.pdf'
```

Result of `ls -leO@pd -n ~/Documents/0_Travail ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-* ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-*/Reunions-Talks`is:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 504  20  -  352 22 avr 13:43 /Users/loic/Documents/0_Travail/
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@ 23 504  20  -  736 22 avr 12:05 /Users/loic/Documents/0_Travail/03-Soleil/
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@ 40 504  20  - 1280 28 avr 16:22 /Users/loic/Documents/0_Travail/03-Soleil/Reunions-Talks/
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32
```

Comment: These should be very reproducible and if you reported them to Apple support, I bet they would help troubleshoot and file it up to engineering to get you the absolute best permanent fix if this isn't just routine corruption and is truly a bug in the code. It's not wrong to ask here for help, but there's a lot of troubleshooting that might assist here.

Comment: I can't reproduce this here. Maybe a permission issue? Can you open Terminal, run `mkdir -p abc123/a/b/c/d`, navigate down to `d` in Finder and then use control-click to get back to `abc123`?

Comment: I have edited my post to indicate that this only happens with certain folders and I have not been able to identify why some folders have this problem and others do not. I will check in more details if this a permission issue.

Comment: Did you try the example I gave you, what happened? Can you list some specific paths where the problem occurs, and where it doesn‘t? Without details it will be difficult for anybody here to provide input.

Comment: Yes I tried your example, and it did not lead to issues. Would it be wise that I reset the permissions for the entire Documents/ folder. I saw for instance that some folders have staff and everyone to Read only, while some have Forbidden access.

Comment: For instance my Documents folder has the following rights:
me: Read & Write
everyone: No Access
(and the staff user is missing)

Comment: Screenshots are usually better than words. Or at least specifics about which folder have which permissions and whether they allow navigation or not. Keep in mind that we can‘t see your computer screen, so we only know what you share with us.

Comment: Hi @nohillside. Yes I know, but this behaviour is not so easy to show and I felt it easier to describe in words. I will try to add a few pictures. There is no obvious rational to me why it affects certain folders and others not. Except if there are some weird (ACL related?) permissions somewhere.

Comment: Screenshot helps. Can you open Terminal, run `ls -leO@pd ~/Documents/0_Travail ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-* ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-*/Reunions-Talk` (that's one command) and add the result to the question, as text (and formatted as code)?

Comment: Thanks. Permissions seem fine. You could try `xattr -r -d com.apple.FinderInfo ~/Documents` but I doubt it will help.

Comment: Can you please confirm I have to use `sudo` as I am not a sudoer by deliberate choice

Comment: No `sudo` required, I would have been specific if it would be needed here.

Comment: Thank you, then I receive, hundreds of `[Errno 13] Permission denied`.

Comment: Can you copy/paste some of these error lines into the question? And rerun the command from before with an additional option `ls -leO@pd ~/Documents/0_Travail ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-* ~/Documents/0_Travail/03-*/Reunions-Talk`.

Comment: Hi @nohillside, the option is identical I think. I added the error lines

Comment: Indeed, please add `-n`.

Comment: I have added the indicated option.

Comment: Hi @nohillside, I was wondering about the meaning of the `xattr` errors.

Comment: You need to check the permissions of the files throwing the error. As for the directory problem: I‘ running out of ideas.

Comment: Could you please recommend a proper way to do this, I have a bit given up since the ACL's were implemented

Comment: The ls command from above shows permissions.

Comment: I am still quite confused. Should files in `Documents/`have read-only access to users `staff` and `everyone`?

Comment: Makes sense, unless you want to allow any user on your Mac to modify your files.

Comment: That goes a bit beyond the scope of the question here. We probably have some Q&A on this already in AD.

Comment: Yes, I confirm this is not the issue, I have reinstated `staff`with read-only access and still the same issue as indicated. I have reported the bug (?) to Apple, hoping they can help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a bug, you should be able to reproduce this on a totally clean installation. I would make a backup and then erase the Mac and do nothing other than test for the bug.

- At that point, I would report it to Apple officially with logs using the Feedback Assistant (spotlight will show it to you) so they can fix it permanently.

If you can't reproduce it on a new clean install - then you can try bringing you backup to the Mac and see if that's the source of the issues or you just had an unlucky break (my hunch as to the cause). Perhaps boot to recovery OS and run Disk Utility to be sure the filesystem is healthy after you make a backup and before the erase install.

Comment: I reported the bug to Apple using the Feedback Assistant. Unfortunately it is too costly in terms of professional time to test a full reinstallation. The bug is still here in 13.4

Comment: That's a great compromise @leparc - time can be in short supply, and as long as you have a backup you can wait to reinstall until you need to