# Entire folders cannot be searched

Tags: finder, spotlight

I have reinstalled my entire system from a Time Machine backup and I am still having problems with the folder structure / permissions in MacOS Ventura 13.3.1(a).

One of the bugs is when I use the search box in the Finder:

- if I select certain folders, I will get no results, even if the file I am looking for is in that folder.
- However, if I search the whole disk ("This Mac"), the file is found.

It may or not be related to [another bug if I have mentioned previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459092/bug-in-the-finder-on-ventura-13-3-1/459093#459093)

Many thanks for your help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I'd test 13.4. If it is a bug, they *might* have fixed it.

Comment: Which folders can't be searched?

Comment: This is a good point. For example, any search in my home folder does not give any results. The same applies to all the folders in it.

Comment: The problem was solved when I updated to 13.4. So I guess the Spotlight index rebuild induced by the update did the trick. The other bug (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459092/bug-in-the-finder-on-ventura-13-3-1/459093#459093) is unsolved.